# Django Templatetag with User objects

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to pass the user objects to my template via a templatetag. I first tried simple_tag but apparently it is only for strings? Anyway this is what I have so far:

templatetags/profiles.py

```
from django.template import Library, Node, Template, VariableDoesNotExist, TemplateSyntaxError, \
                            Variable
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.db import models



class userlist(Node):
    def __init__(self, format_string):
        self.format_string = format_string
    def render(self, context):
        try:
        users = self.format_string
        return users
        except VariableDoesNotExist:
            return None


def get_profiles(parser, token):
    return userlist(User.objects.all())

register = Library()
register.tag('get_profiles', get_profiles)
```

This is what I have in my template to test it:

```
{% load profiles %} 
{% get_profiles %}
{% for p in get_profiles %} {{ p }} {% endfor %}
```

I only get `[, , , , ]` printed out or if I change `User.objects.all()` to `User.objects.count()` I get the correct number. The for iteration in my template doesn't seem to do anything. what is wrong?

Comment: User.objects.get(username='test') gives me the user "test" correctly also. Just when I try to pass all my objects and iterate I wont get anything with that for loop in my template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is format string? You need to call the template tag like this:

```
{% get_all_users as allusers %}
{% for user in allusers %}
     {{ user.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

So you need a template tag like

```
class GetAllUsers(Node):
    def __init__(self, varname):
        # Save the variable that we will assigning the users to
        self.varname = varname
def render(self, context):
        # Save all the user objects to the variable and return the context to the template
        context[self.varname] = User.objects.all()
        return ''

@register.tag(name="get_all_users") 
def get_all_users(parser, token):
    # First break up the arguments that have been passed to the template tag
    bits = token.contents.split()
    if len(bits) != 3:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError, "get_all_users tag takes exactly 2 arguments"
    if bits[1] != 'as':
        raise TemplateSyntaxError, "1st argument to get_all_users tag must be 'as'"
    return GetAllUsers(bits[2])
```

Comment: {% get_all_users as allusers %}
This gives me an Caught TypeError while rendering: unhashable type: 'list'. I tried {% for user in get_all_users %} {{ user }} {% endfor %}. It doesn't complain but yet it doesn't print out anything either.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had to change return GetAllUsers(bits)
to return GetAllUsers(bits[2]) but otherwise it was flawless. Thanks again!